# How to decrypt text in PHP that is encrypted by Rijndael in .NET

Tags: php, .net, encryption

We use **.NET** to encrypt text with the following procedure:

```
RijndaelManaged rijndaelCipher = new RijndaelManaged();
rijndaelCipher.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
rijndaelCipher.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
rijndaelCipher.KeySize = 128;
rijndaelCipher.BlockSize = 128;
```

One of our partners try to use **PHP** to decrypt it, but failed. 
Do you know PHP got existing library to help them out?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
$decode = trim(base64_decode($decrypt));
$iv = mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB), MCRYPT_RAND);
$decrypted = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $mc_key, $decode, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv);
```